# adding of check boxes in a group box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a groupbox with 12 checkboxes(containing months of the year). I need to calculate and display the value in a text box.

For example if one check box is checked then on clicking the button calculate, it should be able to display the value 500 in the text box, if two checkboxes is checked then the total should be 1000, if three check boxes then total should be 1500 and so on

i have started like this

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    counter = counter + 500
```

Been breaking my head on this for quite some time now :(

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a for loop to look at all checked box in the group box

```
'Initialize the total value
Dim Total As Integer = 0

'Loop all controls in the group box
For Each ctrl As Control In GroupBox1.Controls

    'Only calculate if the control is a check box
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then

        'Validate if the checkbox is checked
        If CType(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked Then

            'Add 500 for each checked checkbox
            Total += 500
        End If

    End If

Next

TextBox1.Text = Total.ToString
```

Comment: 'For' loop control variable cannot be of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'. C:\Users\Shamidha krishi\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\myapps\myapps\Payment.vb 34 14 myapps

Comment: Sorry I missed `EACH` after `FOR`, it should be `For Each`

Answer (score 0):

Two other options spring to mind:

set up the .CheckedChanged event along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Month_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Ctrl1.CheckedChanged, Ctrl2.CheckedChanged, Ctrl3.CheckedChanged, ... etc.

if sender.checked then
    Total +=500
else
    Total-= 500
End if

end sub
```

That way you won't need the calculate button.

I think you could also use a CheckedListBox and use

```
Me.Ctrls.CheckedItems.Count * 500
```

either in the calculate button sub or in the SlectedIndexChanged event But I've not tried this